# Compilation error for Class.isInstance and Class.cast

Tags: java, class, compilation

My code is as below, but I got compilation error

```
The method isInstance(MyClass) is undefined for the type Class<T>
The method cast(MyClass) is undefined for the type Class<T>
```

Code:

```
 public <T extends MyClass> Collection<T> myMethodName(
      Class<T> theClass) {
    Set<T> result = Sets.newHashSet();

    for (MyClass myObject : myObjects) {
      if ( theClass.isInstance(myObject)) {
        result.add(theClass.cast(myObject));
      }
    }

    return result;
  }
```

Comment: What are you compiling this with?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `java.lang.Class`? If it is then it should definitely work because the parameter type is `Object` for both the methods.

Comment: Works for me (after converting to an SSCCE) both in Eclipse and on the command line with javac JDK 1.7.0. Can you enhance your question with a complete, compilable example and add the command / IDE which causes the error?